# jquery json loop through data - just cant figure this out

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a button on a pge thats fetches json data from a php page,

the data seems to arrive ok but i have gone through hundreds of examples and i just cant seem to reference the returned data, here is my script:

EDITED SCRIPT from previous comments

```
 $('#geo_batch').click(function (){
            var ajax_load = "<label><img src='/images/icons/loadinfo.gif' alt='saving location...' /> Loading data...</label>";
            $("#batch_detail").html(ajax_load);
            $('#batch_buttons').hide();
            var form = $("form"); //Grab the form element from the DOM 
            //alert(form.serialize());
            var mydata = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: 'geo_getupdate_list.php', 
                data: mydata,  
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(dat) {
                    alert('dat:'+ typeof dat ) //RETURNS STRING
                    //alert(dat.location[0].id_mdt); //RETURNS UNDEFINED
                    // Cache the batch_detail element
                    var $detail = $("#batch_detail").html('<label>Locations have been retrieved:<br>' + dat + '<label>');
                    $('#batch_buttons').show();
                    // Instead of several .append() calls on the same element, create a 
                    //   single string, and do one.
                    var appendString = '';
                    for(var key in dat) { alert(key); return false; };
                    /*for(i=0; i < count; i++){
                        appendString += 'display address: ' + data.location[i].displayaddr_mdt + 'flag: ' + data.location[i].flag_mdt;
                    }*/
                    $detail.append(appendString);
                }, 
                error: function(dat) { //Triggered if an error communicating with server   
                     //alert('fail');
                     $("#batch_detail").html('<label>There was an error: '+dat+'<label>');  
                     $('#batch_buttons').show();
                }
            });  
            return false; //Ignore the default behavior of the button click  
        });
```

the json that is returned is:

```
{"location":[{"id_mdt":"5","idetp_mdt":"1","name_mdt":null,"geoaddr_mdt":null,"displayaddr_mdt":"31a Arundel Gardens London W11 2LW","telephone_mdt":null,"email_mdt":null,"website_mdt":"http:\/\/","lat_mdt":"51.513561","lng_mdt":"-0.206519","active_mdt":"1","flag_mdt":"1","id_etp":"1","name_etp":"Stockist","icon_etp":null},{"id_mdt":"1","idetp_mdt":"1","name_mdt":null,"geoaddr_mdt":null,"displayaddr_mdt":"via todde 29 Ales Sardegna 09091","telephone_mdt":null,"email_mdt":null,"website_mdt":"http:\/\/","lat_mdt":"39.7670964","lng_mdt":"8.813689","active_mdt":"1","flag_mdt":"1","id_etp":"1","name_etp":"Stockist","icon_etp":null},{"id_mdt":"4","idetp_mdt":"1","name_mdt":null,"geoaddr_mdt":null,"displayaddr_mdt":"31a Arundel Gardens London W11 2LW","telephone_mdt":null,"email_mdt":null,"website_mdt":"http:\/\/","lat_mdt":"51.513561","lng_mdt":"-0.206519","active_mdt":"1","flag_mdt":"1","id_etp":"1","name_etp":"Stockist","icon_etp":null},{"id_mdt":"3","idetp_mdt":"1","name_mdt":null,"geoaddr_mdt":null,"displayaddr_mdt":"31a Arundel Gardens London W11 2LW","telephone_mdt":null,"email_mdt":null,"website_mdt":"http:\/\/","lat_mdt":"51.513561","lng_mdt":"-0.206519","active_mdt":"1","flag_mdt":"1","id_etp":"1","name_etp":"Stockist","icon_etp":null},{"id_mdt":"6","idetp_mdt":"1","name_mdt":null,"geoaddr_mdt":null,"displayaddr_mdt":"31a Arundel Gardens London W11 2LW","telephone_mdt":null,"email_mdt":null,"website_mdt":null,"lat_mdt":"51.513561","lng_mdt":"-0.206519","active_mdt":"1","flag_mdt":"1","id_etp":"1","name_etp":"Stockist","icon_etp":null},{"id_mdt":"7","idetp_mdt":"1","name_mdt":"Test","geoaddr_mdt":null,"displayaddr_mdt":"31a Arundel Gardens London W11 2LW","telephone_mdt":null,"email_mdt":null,"website_mdt":null,"lat_mdt":"51.513561","lng_mdt":"-0.206519","active_mdt":"1","flag_mdt":"1","id_etp":"1","name_etp":"Stockist","icon_etp":null}]}
```

how do i access the data in the array?

i have tried so many examples on here and other places and i cant get any to work.
I think it may be to do with the returned json object it has [ symbols in it which i think is wrong?

the php i have to generate the json is as follows:

```
//have defined a recordset called $rs_locations
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_locations)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
$jsondata = json_encode($rows);
// trying to strip out the [ ] brackets but doesn't work
str_replace ("[", "", $jsondata);
str_replace ("]", "", $jsondata);
echo($jsondata);
```

any ideas anyone, i am so stuck, thanks

Comment: At the beginning of the `success:` callback, what happens if you do `alert(data.location[0].id_mdt);` ?

Comment: Verify your JSON returned. Are you certain it is `{"location":` ? Or is it `{"locations":` or `{"rows":` instead?

Comment: I'd highly suggest you to NOT prefix regular variables with $ - that should be used only for jQuery objects, e.g. stuff like `var $this = $(this);`. Additionally you should not make local variables global, i.e. declare them with the `var` keyword.

So, replace `$locdata = data;` with `var locdata = data;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Your dataType property is mis-spelled.

It should be `dataType`, not `datatype`.

Also, try changing the `data` parameter to some other name, like `dat`. I've seen problems with that before when your `$.ajax()` call has the `data` property set.

```
success: function( dat ) {
   // Then change all references from data to dat
```

---

Try this for your `success:` callback.

You were fetching the same `#batch_detail` element several times and continuously calling `.append()` on that element.

This way you cache a reference to the element, create a single String to append, and then do the append once after the loop is done.

The specific trouble you were having was that you needed to reference the Array stored at `data.location` directly.

```
 success: function(dat) {
     // Cache the batch_detail element
     var $detail = $("#batch_detail").html('<label>Locations have been retrieved:<br>' + dat + '<label>');
     $('#batch_buttons').show();
     var count = dat.location.length - 1;
       // Instead of several .append() calls on the same element, create a 
       //   single string, and do one.
     var appendString = '';
     for(i=0; i < count; i++){
         appendString += 'display address: ' + dat.location[i].displayaddr_mdt + 'flag: ' + dat.location[i].flag_mdt;
     }
     $detail.append( appendString );
 },
```

Comment: ahhhh nice! i was wondering what all the jqueryfy errors meant in firebug!!, thanks for that, maybe it would be better to store the original html in the appendstring and do a .html(appendstring). thats good thanks but the data.location still returns indefined, are you sure its not to do with the '[' and ']' crackets in the json?

Comment: @Dizzy - The `[]` are fine. They denote an Array. If `data.location` is undefined, then check to make sure that `location` is the correct key. It would seem like `locations` (plural) may be more likely.

Comment: if your intrested you can see the page i am working on here: http://www.focus-on-plants.com/admin/stokists/

Comment: @Dizzy - Not sure if you're still with me here, but tell me what happens if you do this in your success: `alert( typeof data )` Also, I added an edit to my answer at the top.

Comment: ahh ok have disabled the login, have a look now, sorry i was following the other thread
the for(var key in data) { alert(key); return false; }//ALERTS 0

Comment: @Dizzy - I'm working on your page. See the edit at the top of my answer. Your `dataType` property is misspelled. When I change it on your page, it goes to the `error:` callback. Investigating...

Comment: @Dizzy - ...also, is there a reason you're using an old version of jQuery?

Comment: it appears that dat (changed it from data) is a string, if i chage it to dataType: 'json' i get an xhtml request error

Comment: @Dizzy - You still have `datatype` instead of `dataType`. Yes, I know it sends you to the `error:` callback, but it focuses the problem to the actual issue. Without `dataType: 'json'` you're just going to end up with a `String` that doesn't get parsed.

Comment: @Dizzy - Invalid JSON is now being returned. You have an extra set of quotation marks around the `[...]` portion of the JSON. So instead of `{"location":"[{...}]"}` it should look like `{"location":[{...}]}` This is why it is going to the `error:` callback.

Comment: @Dizzy - Looks like the proper JSON is now being returned. Just be sure to put the `count` variable back in there, and update all occurrences of `data` to `dat`. You missed a couple. With those changes, I have it working on my end. I'll update my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: thank you so so much for your time and patience, i learnt a lot!! you have better eyes than me, 2 days ive been trying to work this out, now maybe i can get on to the next bit :))P

Comment: @Dizzy - Glad I could help. If you're not doing it now, I'd highly recommend using `console.log()` along with Safari/Chrome/Firefox developer tools to observe data that seems to be giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your script right, you have to get the `location` array from `data` first:

```
var locations = data.location;
for(var location in locations) {
    console.debug(locations[location]);
}
```

Comment: so [ ] characters are ok in the json then?

Comment: yeah. `for` loops through `Objects` as well. `Key` would be an `Integer`OR `String` then. Btw: Accessing Object-Values is possible through `obj['key']` or `obj.key`

Comment: var locations = data.location;
for(var location in locations) {
    /// do stuff
    ("#batch_detail").append(this['id_mdt']);
};
this does not output anything???

Comment: try `var locations = data.location; for(var location in locations) { var current = locations[location]; $("#batch_detail").append(current.id_mdt); }; `

Comment: var locations = data.location;
        alert(locations);
      for(var location in locations) {
       /// do stuff
        $("#batch_detail").append(location+' is the location');
        }; returns undefined....     /// do stuff
        $("#batch_detail").append(location+' is the location');};

Comment: what does `alert(locations)` return?

Comment: var locations = data.location; 
     alert('locations: '+locations+'<br>');//REURNS UNDEFINED
     for(var location in locations) { ??NO LOOP HAPPENS
      var current = locations[location];
      alert('current: '+current+'<br>');
       
      $("#batch_detail").append(current.id_mdt); 
     };

Comment: huh. strange... then you probably have to loop through data directly: `for(var id in data) { var location = data[id]; $("#batch_detail").append(location.id_mdt); }`. Even though I wouldn't understand that :]

Comment: if your intrested you can look at the page, select flagged locations and click the batch button it out puts trhe json and it is called location! http://www.focus-on-plants.com/admin/stokists/

Comment: it appears that dat (changed it from data) is a string